# Question about the region plan when we transformations pairs of Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random variables.

Let $Z=g(X,Y)$ a function of two random variables.
To find the CDF of $Z$ we have

\begin{align}
P\{Z\leq z\}=&P\{g(X,Y)\leq z\}\\
            =&\iint_{g(x,y)\leq z}^{}f_X(x)f_Y(y) dxdy. 
\end{align}

In Books, The inequality $g(x, y) ≤ z$ defines a region in the $(x, y)$ plane.
How we find this region? For exaple $Z=X+Y$.

Comment: For the first part "...$g(x, y) ≤ z$ defines a region ... How do we find this region?" This has to be done case-by-case and there's no general procedure that will work for one blindly plug things in. For the example of $Z = X+Y$, the region for $P\{Z < k\}$ is just $x+y < k$ which is below the straightline $x+y=k$ for the given $k$.

Comment: For the second part, the notational convention is that capitals are random variables while the lowercases are dummy variables. The expression $\displaystyle P\{Z\leq z\} = \iint_{g(s,t)\leq z}^{}f_X(s)f_Y(t) dsdt$ says exactly the same thing as with using the dummy $x$ and $y$. In your example of $P\{X\leq Y\}$, having capital $Y$ in the integration limit is just wrong (for multiple reasons), mainly because your choice of dummy variable for outer integral is $y$. For example, another correct way is $\displaystyle P\{X\leq Y\}=\int_{w=-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{u=-\infty}^{w}f_X(u)f_Y(w) dudw.$

Comment: Honestly this question post should be closed as currently it is not quite up to the standard of this site. In particular, asking more than multiple questions in a single post is discouraged, especially when they are not really mathematically related.